# Python generate all possible strings of length n

Tags: python

I am learning ethical hacking. I have the hash key of a password and the crypt algorithm (sha256/sha512). I want to parse all the strings from a file and to check if the hash of the password matches the hash of each of the string from the file.

The generated String may contain small letters, big letters and numbers.

Any ideas how to generate all the possible Strings of length n which may contain letters and numbers?

Comment: [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) (with `repeat=n`) might come in handy.

Comment: it's not duplicate as there are no digits included

Comment: There's no structural difference. You just need to extend the alphabet.

Comment: A better approach is to use lists of frequent passwords, see  [SecLists](https://github.com/danielmiessler/SecLists/tree/master/Passwords).
.

Comment: Interesting link. Anyway I want to implement by myself. Also when there are password validation rules it may be easier to generate all the possible strings and then just check them

Comment: For a 8 character passwords there are about 100,000,000,000,000 possibilities. Also see: Infosec [password-cracking-tools](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/10-popular-password-cracking-tools/)  
Advanced Password Recovery [hashcat](https://hashcat.net/hashcat/)

Comment: these are just permutations of chars in a set with repetitions. In the case of omitting special chars, there are 52^8 posibilities. So I should think about improvements

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a piece of code that uses [[Python 3.Docs]: itertools.**product**(**iterables, repeat=1*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). 
Note that the number of generated strings is `62 ** length`, so for testing purposes use **small values** for *length*:

```py
import string
import itertools


def generate_strings(length=3):
    chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits  # "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
    for item in itertools.product(chars, repeat=length):
        yield "".join(item)
```

Comment: what is count var?

Comment: It's `n` (generated string's length).

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
print([''.join(x) for x in itertools.product('abcABC123', repeat=3)])
['aaa',
 'aab',
 'aac',
 'aaA',
 'aaB',
 'aaC',
 'aa1',
 'aa2',
 'aa3',
 'aba',
...
```

Just add the remaining characters you need to the input string. You can use the constants from the `strings` module for this.

Be aware that this quickly grows. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```
from itertools import product
from string import ascii_letters, digits

for i in product(ascii_letters + digits, repeat=n):
    print(''.join(i))
```

Comment: This will only generate strings where each letter is contained at max once.

Comment: permutations won't allow repeated letters though, right? Don't you want ``itertools.combinations_with_replacement``?

Comment: You're right, should be product.

Comment: Wouldn't it raise `TypeError` when not specifying `repeat=n`?